# How to solve second condition in operator if; android

Tags: android

Whats is wrong in code bellow?
App gives an error when i click a button and edittext is empty, and if edittext contains zero or another number it is all right...

Thanks in advance

```
public void onMyButtonClick(View view)
    {
        EditText rateet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rateet);
        if (rateet.getText().toString().length()==0 | Double.parseDouble(rateet.getText().toString())==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong rate!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }      


    else {
        double r1=Double.parseDouble(rateet.getText().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("rate", r1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i delete one of conditions it is all right too

Comment: Are you saying you want the app to give those errors, but it currently doesn't?

Comment: I mean app is crashed.

Comment: parseDouble throws an exception if the contents of the string is not a number.  You need to catch that exception and deal with it.

Comment: i use a special mode for keyboard in this edittext: android:inputType="number" ; there is only number. problem in the checking of length, but i don't know that exactly

Comment: Also, you don't need the `return` statement. Once you're inside the `if`  and it's been executed you will return anyway, the `else` code will not be looked at/executed.

Comment: Binary, you are right:)

Comment: It seems, that operator doesn't notice the condition about lenght. Because of this app is crashes.

Comment: Just an idea but do you need it to be empty to start with? You could use `setText` to set it to zero to begin with and then you know there is already something there.

Comment: **In addition**, this line is wrong `if (rateet.getText().toString().length()==0 | Double.parseDouble(rateet.getText().toString())==0){` This **|** should be written so **||**.

Comment: Der Golem, thanks a lot! exactly this (||) was the reason of crashing)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this expression:

```
Double.parseDouble(rateet.getText().toString())==0
```

When the EditText is empty, the String returned is an empty String, which is not a valid double constant.  You have to test for the empty String first before calling `parseDouble()`.

You should also catch `NumberFormatException` to handle other cases where the String in EditText is not a valid number.